# biomaRt - NameSpace loading failed

Tags: r, dbplyr, biomart

I installed biomaRt after the latest R update and I am having problems.
Whenever I try to call `library("biomaRt")` it gives me the following error:

```
Error in completeSubclasses(classDef2, class1, obj, where) : 
  trying to get slot "subclasses" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots
Error: caricamento pacchetto o namespace fallito per ‘biomaRt’:
 .onLoad fallito in loadNamespace() per 'dbplyr', dettagli:
  chiamata: setClass(cl, contains = c(prevClass, "VIRTUAL"), where = where)
  errore: errore nelle classi contenute ("character") per la classe “ident”; definizione di classe rimossa da ‘dbplyr’
```

I tried to re-install it and update dbplyr as well but the problem is not solved. Any suggestions?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Italian_Italy.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Italian_Italy.utf8    LC_MONETARY=Italian_Italy.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Italian_Italy.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] fgsea_1.24.0           colorspace_2.1-0       ggtree_3.6.2           gson_0.1.0             qvalue_2.30.0         
  [6] XVector_0.38.0         aplot_0.1.10           rstudioapi_0.14        farver_2.1.1           graphlayouts_0.8.4    
 [11] ggrepel_0.9.3          bit64_4.0.5            AnnotationDbi_1.60.2   fansi_1.0.4            scatterpie_0.1.8      
 [16] codetools_0.2-19       splines_4.2.3          cachem_1.0.7           GOSemSim_2.24.0        knitr_1.42            
 [21] polyclip_1.10-4        jsonlite_1.8.4         GO.db_3.16.0           png_0.1-8              ggforce_0.4.1         
 [26] BiocManager_1.30.20    compiler_4.2.3         httr_1.4.5             Matrix_1.5-3           fastmap_1.1.1         
 [31] lazyeval_0.2.2         cli_3.6.1              tweenr_2.0.2           htmltools_0.5.5        prettyunits_1.1.1     
 [36] tools_4.2.3            igraph_1.4.1           gtable_0.3.3           glue_1.6.2             GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9
 [41] reshape2_1.4.4         dplyr_1.1.1            fastmatch_1.1-3        Rcpp_1.0.10            enrichplot_1.18.4     
 [46] Biobase_2.58.0         vctrs_0.6.1            Biostrings_2.66.0      ape_5.7-1              nlme_3.1-162          
 [51] ggraph_2.1.0           xfun_0.38              stringr_1.5.0          lifecycle_1.0.3        clusterProfiler_4.6.2 
 [56] XML_3.99-0.14          DOSE_3.24.2            zlibbioc_1.44.0        MASS_7.3-58.2          scales_1.2.1          
 [61] tidygraph_1.2.3        hms_1.1.3              parallel_4.2.3         RColorBrewer_1.1-3     yaml_2.3.7            
 [66] memoise_2.0.1          gridExtra_2.3          ggplot2_3.4.2          downloader_0.4         ggfun_0.0.9           
 [71] HDO.db_0.99.1          yulab.utils_0.0.6      stringi_1.7.12         RSQLite_2.3.0          S4Vectors_0.36.2      
 [76] tidytree_0.4.2         BiocGenerics_0.44.0    BiocParallel_1.32.6    GenomeInfoDb_1.34.9    rlang_1.1.0           
 [81] pkgconfig_2.0.3        bitops_1.0-7           evaluate_0.20          lattice_0.20-45        purrr_1.0.1           
 [86] treeio_1.22.0          patchwork_1.1.2        cowplot_1.1.1          shadowtext_0.1.2       bit_4.0.5             
 [91] tidyselect_1.2.0       plyr_1.8.8             magrittr_2.0.3         R6_2.5.1               IRanges_2.32.0        
 [96] generics_0.1.3         DBI_1.1.3              pillar_1.9.0           withr_2.5.0            KEGGREST_1.38.0       
[101] RCurl_1.98-1.12        tibble_3.2.1           crayon_1.5.2           utf8_1.2.3             rmarkdown_2.21        
[106] viridis_0.6.2          progress_1.2.2         grid_4.2.3             data.table_1.14.8      blob_1.2.4            
[111] digest_0.6.31          tidyr_1.3.0            gridGraphics_0.5-1     stats4_4.2.3           munsell_0.5.0         
[116] viridisLite_0.4.1      ggplotify_0.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Translating the error message into English (using ChatGPT) I get the following translation:

```
Error in completeSubclasses(classDef2, class1, obj, where) :
trying to get slot "subclasses" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'biomaRt':
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'dbplyr', details:
call: setClass(cl, contains = c(prevClass, "VIRTUAL"), where = where)
error: error in the contained classes ("character") for the class "ident"; 
       class definition removed from 'dbplyr'
```

Based on this message, it appears that the version of dbplyr you are using has had a class definition removed that biomaRt needs to run. Perhaps you need to go back to a previous version of dbplyr? Alternatively, you could post this as a bug on biomaRt and wait for the maintainer to update their package to work with the latest version of dbplyr.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately even with two older version ofthe package the problem remains unsolved. I will ask in the bioconductor page

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I dont think this will be an accepted answer, but reinstalling `dbplyr` and restarting the Rsession fixed the problem for me. I still dont know why the problem occurred in the first place though